# I am getting Bareword error in perl file

Tags: perl

I  am executing my perl files in a batch. I am pasting all the name of the perl file in a batch file and executing it. I am giving a small demo of the file.

The batch file /10BT_run1.Amset contains:

```
Perl ../tools/test_driver_multi_aid_sequential.pl e2_h/l2_mode/set_bwprf  #this is  line 4 of the batch file
```

I am getting error like

```
Bareword found where operator expected at ./10BT_run1.Amset line 4, near "/tools       /test_driver_multi_aid_sequential"
    (Missing operator before test_driver_multi_aid_sequential?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./10BT_run1.Amset line 4, near "/l2_mode/set_bwprf"
    (Missing operator before et_bwprf?)
```

Comment: try placing the entire input in double quotes `" "`

Comment: or maybe single quotes.single quotes will help you to ignore `/` in file path.

Comment: adding single quote to the start of the line i.e 'Perl ../tools/test_driver_multi_aid_sequential.pl e2_h/l2_mode/set_bwprf' or only arguments??

Comment: @Nitesh Windows shell does not recognise single quote as quotes. What I am curious about is why you are getting a perl error in your batch file? Are you executing the batch file as a perl script?

Comment: @TLP : yes i am executing as a perl script

Comment: @Nitesh You are aware that you cannot execute a command like `perl myscript.pl` in a perl script, right? Are you using windows? I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

You are somehow executing the batch file (`./10BT_run1.Amset`) using `perl` instead of `cmd`.

Answer (score -1):

you can run the perl files as argument to perl interpreter

```
perl "../tools/test_driver_multi_aid_sequential.pl e2_h/l2_mode/set_bwprf"
```

if you are going to use " in between the arguments separate those as escaping sequence like 
\"

It will avoid the error that you have mentioned